# Simplifying this equation with factoring

Tags: functions, polynomials

I don't know how to simplify this question with factoring, any help on this?

> Consider $g(x)=x^2-16, h(x)=x^2+x-20, d(x)=x^2-25$. Find $$\dfrac{d(d(x))}{h(g(x))}$$

This is what I got after plugging in the equations.

$$\dfrac{(x^2-30)^2}{(x+4)^2(x-4)^2+(x+4)(x-4)-20}$$

Comment: **Hint:** $d(d(x))=\left(x^2-25\right)^2-25, h(g(x)) = x^2+\left(x^2-16\right)^2-36$. Can you continue?

Comment: @Moo Is it $\frac {(x+5)^2(x-5)^2}{(x+6)(x-6)(x+4)^2(x-4)^2}$?

Comment: Result is:$\dfrac{x^2-30}{x^2-11}$, which should provide another hint.

Comment: @Moo Can you type up an answer and explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given;

$$g(x)=x^2-16, h(x)=x^2+x-20, d(x)=x^2-25$$

To find $d(d(x))$, wherever we see an $x$ in $d(x)$, we substitute $d(x)$. We have:

$$d(d(x)) = (d(x))^2 - 25 = (d(x))^2 - 5^2 = (d(x)+5)(d(x)-5)=((x^2-25) + 5)((x^2-25)- 5) = (x^2-20)(x^2-30)$$

Note, for the denominator, we can look to simplfy life:

$$h(g(x)) = (g(x))^2 + g(x) - 20 = (g(x) - 4)(g(x) +5)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see now, you have to factor and then substitute into the factored form. Or at least that seems the easiest way to do it.